# Does PHP support long bit array?

Tags: php, bitset

So I'm trying to work on a web service that deals with long bit arrays (100+ bits).

Can anyone suggest a class in PHP that deals with long bit arrays?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking for an off-site resource, but rather for code (a PHP class). Could be wrong, though.

Comment: @showdev same thing...

Comment: @Neal Not the same thing -- There's a different closing flag for questions asking for code vs. questions asking for an off-site resource. But I guess the end result is similar.

Comment: I think the OP asks for something similar to `bitset` in c++, which is really useful. And just using ordinary integers limits the bitset to 64. Don't see why is this off-topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP doesn't support long bit arrays, you can use ordinary arrays and calculate proper offset as (this is sample for 32 bit architecture):

```
$array = [];
$bitToSet = 33;
setbit($array, $bitToSet);
print_r($array);

echo getbit($array, $bitToSet-1) . "\n";
echo getbit($array, $bitToSet) . "\n";
echo getbit($array, $bitToSet+2) . "\n";

function setbit(&$array, $bitNumber) {
    $arrayIdx = $bitNumber >> 5; // I suppose 32 bit int
    $bitIdx = $bitNumber & 0x1f;
    if (!isset($array[$arrayIdx])) $array[$arrayIdx] = 0;
    $array[$arrayIdx] = (1<<$bitIdx); 
}
function uRShift($a, $b) {
    if($b == 0) return $a;
    return ($a >> $b) & ~(1<<(8*PHP_INT_SIZE-1)>>($b-1));
}
function getbit(&$array, $bitNumber) {
    $arrayIdx = $bitNumber >> 5;
    $bitIdx = $bitNumber & 0x1f;
    if (!isset($array[$arrayIdx])) $array[$arrayIdx] = 0;
    return uRShift($array[$arrayIdx], $bitIdx)&1;
}
```

also you can check about [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) and [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php), second not the best option anyway

Comment: Downvoters: Please explain your votes. It helps everyone learn.

Comment: @showdev this is an answer that would be best suited as a comment as it is just a list of links...

Comment: It's not just a list of links. He's suggesting the use of a particular library as well as specific functions in that library. Regardless, the question is too broad and so the answer can't be very specific. But I don't like the idea of punishing someone who tries to help answer a poorly written question.

Comment: Agreed, @Neal if we handed out downvotes for answers on bad questions I would have no rep left! (edit: from the negative score when I would downvote the answer, not because I would be downvoted ;))